# resolution of string lists to smaller components

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a string list:

```
lis = {"abc","def","def ghi","jkl","ghi","jkl"}
```

I have another string list whose elements contain two members of `lis` joined together and separated by a space character:

```
lis2 = {"abc jkl","def ghi ghi","jkl abc"}
```

I would like to separate each member of `lis2` back into its two components that belong to `lis`:

```
res = {{"abc","jkl"},{"def ghi","ghi"},{"jkl","abc"}}
```

As always, thanks for any ideas.

Here is another sample data set that may state the problem more clearly.

```
newLis = {"Texas State","Ohio","Sam Houston State","Ohio State"}

newLis2 = {{"Texas","State","Ohio","State"},{"Sam","Houston","State","Ohio","State"},{"Ohio","Sam","Houston","State"}}
```

Each of the three elements of newLis2 needs to be decomposed into two elements which are members of newLis:

```
newRes = {{"Texas State","Ohio State"},{"Sam Houston State","Ohio State"},{"Ohio","Sam Houston State"}}
```

*Please see kglr's comment below, he clearly states the problem at (1).  It is best not to make the responders have to guess at the questioner's question :/ *

Comment: `StringSplit /@ lis2` is your after?

Comment: No, that gives:   {{"abc", "jkl"}, {"def", "ghi", "ghi"}, {"jkl", "abc"}}  and I'm aiming for {{"abc","jkl"},{"def ghi","ghi"},{"jkl","abc"}}

Comment: Suite401, updated problem and the original one are very different questions. Maybe you should make it explicit that the question is a two-part one: (1)  Split the strings in  input list so that the resulting strings match the ones in a reference list (`lis`) , and (2) reorganize and `StringJoin` a list of strings so that  the resulting strings match the ones in the references list (`lis`).

Comment: Yes I agree, kglr - thank you for clarifying.  This is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @kglr yes, the task with the second data sample is what you describe at (1) in your comment.  Thank you all for your patience and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alternatives = Apply[Alternatives] @ Reverse @ SortBy[StringLength] @ newLis

StringCases[alternatives] /@  StringRiffle /@ newLis2
```

> ```
> "Sam Houston State" | "Texas State" | "Ohio State" | "Ohio" 
>
> {{"Texas State", "Ohio State"}, 
>  {"Sam Houston State", "Ohio State"}, 
>  {"Ohio", "Sam Houston State"}
> }
> ```

Reverse sort is done to make the longes cases more imprtant. E.g. to match `Ohio State` rather than single `Ohio`.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  @Kuba your solution fails on my data set, but if I replace StringCases[alternatives] /@  StringRiffle /@ newLis2 with StringCases[alternatives] /@  StringRiffle /@ newLis2[1] it succeeds.  I'll call that a win :)

Answer (score 4):

#### [`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html):

```
StringReplace[lis2,   a__ ~~ " " ~~  b__ /;
   (And @@ (Or @@ StringMatchQ[lis, #]& /@ {a, b})) :> {a,b}] /.
  StringExpression -> Identity
```

> {{"abc", "jkl"}, {"def ghi", "ghi"}, {"jkl", "abc"}}

```
StringReplace[lis2,  StartOfString ~~ a : Alternatives @@ lis ~~ 
    " " ~~ b : Alternatives @@ lis ~~ EndOfString :> {a, b}] /. 
 StringExpression -> Identity
```

> {{"abc", "jkl"}, {"def ghi", "ghi"}, {"jkl", "abc"}}

#### [`SequenceAlignment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceAlignment.html):

```
DeleteCases[SequenceAlignment[#, StringJoin @ 
  Riffle[PadRight[lis, 2 Length@lis, "Periodic"], "/"]], _List |  " "] & /@ lis2
```

> {{"abc", "jkl"}, {"def ghi", "ghi"}, {"jkl", "abc"}}

Comment: When I use kglr's second suggestion on the new sample data set, I get the following error message: StringReplace::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringReplace[{{Texas,State,Ohio,State},{Sam,Houston,State,Ohio,State},{Ohio,Sam,Houston,State}},StartOfString~~a:Texas State|Ohio|Sam Houston State|Ohio State~~ ~~b:Texas State|Ohio|Sam Houston State|Ohio State~~EndOfString:>{a,b}].

Comment: @Suite401, just saw your update. This one is not intended to work for your updated problem. Please see my comment below your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `StringSplit` at first and then deal with the special case

```
If[Length[#] == 3, {StringRiffle[#[[;; 2]]], #[[3]]}, #] & /@ StringSplit[lis2]
```