# Resolution of string lists to smaller components II

Tags: string-manipulation

Some weeks ago, I posted a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181803/resolution-of-string-lists-to-smaller-components) which involved creating string pairs from a list of string elements.  One of the answers posted (by Kuba) worked very well until I found an example where it didn't.  Here it is:

```
lis = {"ABCDEFGHI" | "JKLMN OP" | "PQR" | "JKLMN" | "OPXYZ"};
prs = {"JKLMN OP ABCDEFGHI", "JKLMN OPXYZ", "PQR JKLMN"};
```

Given the list **prs** whose elements consist of two members of **lis** separated by a space, the task is to create a modified **prs** where the elements of **prs** are separated into two elements that are members of **lis**.

Kuba's suggestion was essentially:

```
separatedNames = Table[StringSplit[prs[[i]]], {i, Length[prs]}];
alternative = Apply[Alternatives]@Reverse@SortBy[StringLength]@lis[[1]];
res = Partition[Flatten[StringCases[alternative] /@ StringRiffle /@ separatedNames],2]
```

This produces:
     {{"JKLMN OP", "ABCDEFGHI"}, {"JKLMN OP", "PQR"}}

and not the desired:
     {{"JKLMN OP","ABCDEFGHI"},{"JKLMN","OPXYZ"},{"PQR","JKLMN"}}

As always thanks for thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as = Association[StringRiffle@#->#&/@(Join[#, Reverse/@#]&@Subsets[List @@ lis[[1]], {2}])]

as[[prs]]
```

> <|"JKLMN OP ABCDEFGHI" -> {"JKLMN OP", "ABCDEFGHI"}, 
>    "JKLMN OPXYZ" -> {"JKLMN", "OPXYZ"}, "PQR JKLMN" -> {"PQR", "JKLMN"}|>

```
as /@ prs
```

> {{"JKLMN OP", "ABCDEFGHI"}, {"JKLMN", "OPXYZ"}, {"PQR", "JKLMN"}}

Comment: Thank you, kglr, that works well.

Comment: a question: It would be desirable to preserve the order of the pairs in the output of assoc/@prs to be the same as in prs (i.e., the first element would be {"JKLMN OP","ABCDEFGHI"} and not {"ABCDEFGHI","JKLMN OP"}. Thanks

Comment: @Suite401, good point. I will update if i can find a solution.

Comment: That would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Suite401, updated.

Comment: thank you very much! It works well.